# Hair covering in photos

Tags: women, hair-covering, pictures

[Another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4946) asks whether pictures of *erva* are *erva*. My question assumes, for the sake of argument, that they are, and asks: May a married woman show photos of herself with her hair uncovered that were taken, while she was married, in a situation where she is allowed to be with uncovered hair (in her home, as per those halacha opinions)?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, in part of the above-linked question, and in the remaining part of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4946.

Comment: @msh210 - I'd request you leave this question open. Both the "pre-marriage" question and the "pictures of ervah" question do not have clear answers and also do not cover the scope of this question.

Comment: If you edit your question just a bit to differentiate it from the earlier question, then I'd have no problem voting to reopen. What about other issues, such as showing photos of herself (even younger) in a swim suit?

Comment: @SAR622, they did seem to cover the scope AFAICT; even now, this is barely differentiable. If a good question doesn't have a clear answer, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers. I'm going to edit this question now so it's no longer a duplicate of the other. See what you think. If you want, revert my edit, and this question can be reopened anyway if the community agrees with you. If otoh you like my edit, let me know and I'll reopen unless people protest in the comments here.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this isn't a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18271/  In addition to being basically copy-pastes of each other, they're logically equivalent, unless the asker can demonstrate why the halacha should be different depending on when the pictures were taken.  Voting to close.

Comment: Yes this is a copy of 18271.  One of them should be closed as duplicate.  Frustrating that neither one has a good answer.