# Drawing breasts

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, art

Is it an avierah to draw women with their breasts exposed? I have seen paintings by European artists that depict biblical women with their breasts exposed and wondered: if a Jew were to do this, would it be an avierah? I'm asking about drawing/painting something which depicts a woman's exposed breasts (with no woman in front or with you at all).

Comment: I don't know that female breasts always had the highly erotic associations they now have in Western culture. In some locales I suspect exposing your thigh would have been a much greater offense.

Comment: @DoubleAA is it allowed to read Shema regarding a  painting of biblical women with their breasts exposed?

Comment: I thiink that it is allowed, may be more. If a man is allowed to see his wife when she is not nidda, he can draw it. what is the problem. To draw following imagination may be a problem of venishmartem mikol davar ra. the question is good.

Comment: @kouty That's been asked already http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4946/759

Comment: Guys you are going a little off  topic here.. I asked a different question

Comment: @AvishaiEliYahu  read again "To draw..."

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56617

Comment: Avishai, maybe you should [edit] in what you think the problem could be, and what you think the evidence from those paintings suggests. What Aveirah could this possibly be? If I draw a circumpunct, am I liable?

Comment: Is it a problem/avierah to draw breasts is all I am asking.

Comment: Avishai, maybe you should [edit] in what you think the problem could be, and what you think the evidence from those paintings suggests. What Aveirah could this possibly be? If I draw a circumpunct, am I liable?

Comment: Is it permitted to look at [this (warning: graphic)](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-round-brick-2-x-2-with-dome-top-and-safety-stud-with-axle-holder-30367) Lego brick? May one attach two of them next to each other?

Comment: @Adám you just failed the rorchach:)

Comment: @user6591 Take my upvote!

Answer (score -4):

It seems not a problem since many jewish books had that on the title page

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/11696
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/11737
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/11898

so for a woman it should not be a problem (if it is not to be used for erotic proposes)
but for a man their might be a problem of [pornography](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71249/5120) for himself even if it is not for erotic proposes of others

Comment: Many Jewish books were published by non-Jewish printers, and they may have inserted those publisher's pages into the front of the book against the Jewish author's volition. Are you aware of any books published by a Jewish publishing company with these drawings?

Comment: No sources, the example of books you brought up does not imply it's allowed

Comment: @Chaim the jews did not rip them out

Comment: Hazoriz The Maharal's works printed in his own lifetime had pictures with Moshe and Aharon. Moshe had literal horns, like a goat, in that picture. Does that mean Maharal believed that to be the case?

Comment: @user6591 no, it only means jews owning that book did not have a problem with this representation of moshe

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right. Unless you're showing a sefer cover made by a Rishon or an Acharon, I don't believe that would be a credible source.