# Shemira Einayim Online

Tags: halacha, internet, tznius-modesty

In the Mishna Berura 75:7

> one who looks at a woman even at her small finger in order to derive
>   pleasure transgresses the negative commandment 'do not stray after
>   your eyes'  (Bamidbar 15:39). The sages said that even if one
>   possesses torah and good deeds [like Moshe Rabeinu] he will not be
>   clean of the judgment of Gehinom. A casual looking (reiyah b'alma lefi
>   tumo) without deriving pleasure is permitted if not for the aspect of
>   mussar. In the book Minchas Shmuel, he proves that an important person
>   should be heedful in all situations. The Pri Megadim writes that for
>   areas which are normally covered [such as arms or other parts of the
>   body] even casual looking is forbidden.

when using the internet for necessary activities such as work or whatever one inevitably comes across pictures with woman not dressed according to jewish halacha. how is one required to act in this situation according to halacha.

Comment: Accd to the PMG, you shouldn't even casually look.  What are you asking that isn't right there already?

Comment: @DoubleAA asking what one is required to do according to halacha which presumably takes this pri megadim into account

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4946

Comment: @ray Any reason to think the answer isn't just "don't look"?

Comment: @DoubleAA cant know when to look and when not to look till done already

Comment: @ray That's not true. 'Look' is not 'see'

Comment: @DoubleAA pri megadim holds even casual looking (reiyah b'alma lefi tumo) is forbidden for parts normally covered. these ads pop up in your face all the time in many places

Comment: @ray So don't look at them even casually...

Comment: @DoubleAA cant know what they are till too late

Comment: That's not true. just look away...

Comment: @DoubleAA you mean first detection seeing doesnt count

Comment: I don't see how that is "casual looking". Do you?

Comment: Use in Netspark Mobile Internet Filtering Solution.

Answer (score 2):

Download an image blocker. Works wonders. Why fight the battle when you can prevent it from happening in the first place?

Comment: But is that required according to Halakha? Or is it just sound advice?

Comment: and many sites are impossible to navigate without pictures

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not there to begin filtering solution? Today is no shortage of good software. In any case, I recommend using for a phone in Netspark Mobile here: [Netspark Mobile](http://Https://www.netsparkmobile.com/en/)